# How to get image link from product option Id in Magento 2 api

Tags: api, magento, postman, magento2

I am using Magento 2 API to fetch products information and sync with our platform.
I need the product **option image link** by passing **option_id** in API. Is there any API that can return this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such api which can return this kind of data, but Magento is highly customizable, so you can make one custom Api as per your requirements.